# Different result for map() on different arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays

Why do the map() operation generate different output when run on different types of arrays?

I thought `literal` and `obj` below were the same type; why do the resulting array differ? Why are the non-literal array concatenated to one element?

Why do the typed array not create an Array of strings, but return the original typed array? Is there a spec requirement that the map operation can't convert a typed array to a different type?

```
var literal = [1, 2, 3];
var obj = new Array([1, 2, 3]);
var typed = new Uint32Array([1, 2, 3]);


console.log(literal.map(String));
console.log(obj.map(String));
console.log(typed.map(String));
```

Output

```
Array [ "1", "2", "3" ] 
Array [ "1,2,3" ]
Uint32Array [ 1, 2, 3 ]
```

I'm running Firefox 44.0
https://jsfiddle.net/6c8p465r/1/

Comment: `new Array` doesn't really accept an array like that, you end up with an array with just one index, and a `Uint..` array can't hold strings

Comment: **Second case:** The var `obj` is two-dimensional array, so before calling `map`, `toString()` is called on the array. **Third case:** `Uint32Array` as the name says, stores the array of **integers** which cannot be converted to Number.

Comment: Typo there ^^^^: _cannot be converted to **String**_ at the end. _Timeout: can't edit now :(_

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, using the literal array, or using the Array constructor will produce the same result, but you did not use the constructor correctly.

The following will produce an array inside of the array which is why you get only one array returned to you in string format. So when you call map on this, the entire entry that is being mapped is the internal array.

```
new Array([1, 2, 3]); // Produces [[1, 2, 3]]
```

The correct way to create the array the way you want using the Array constructor is to pass in the values as just arguments:

```
new Array(1, 2, 3); // Produces [1, 2, 3]
```

---

The `Uint32Array` has a couple of things going on with it that have to be understood first.

1. It holds unsigned integers (can't be converted to a string)
2. It's constructor is different from the `Array` constructor

If you check out the [Mozilla examples](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Uint32Array#Examples) on `Uint32Array`, you will see that an array of values is expected to be passed into the constructor when using it that way.